# Google chrome freezes on synchronous ajax call in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome, freeze

I searched a lot for this but didn't found one matching exactly to my problem (Although I found certain matching ones but none helping). I'm working on a project to create web application of an ipad app in which I am accessing `webservices` for every task. For example, for login, I've to call an authenticate `webservice` which returns status text in a `xml` string. So, I've to achieve each of these tasks through synchronous `ajax` calls.

So, for example, say, I've a login page where I've to authenticate a user login. So, when a user enters his username and password and submits the form, the loading animation (a simple image with `fixed` position) shows up until the script gets response from the server. Everything is working fine one FF.

My problem starts in Chrome. It doesn't show me the loader. Rather, it freeze up the screen until the page gets some response from the server.

I know, I shouldn't use synchronous ajax but I'm bound to. I can't make changes in the prewritten script so I've to cope with it. So, I'm looking forward to someone who could help me showing up this loader in chrome until the page gets some response from the server.

And hey, just to mention, the page shows up the loader if I put an alert message just before the ajax call.

Comment: aaaaand ___this___ is why you shouldn't use synchronous AJAX

Comment: For your own benefit, learn how to use asynchronous ajax calls.  You'll find yourself applying the same theory to all sorts of things and your coding and apps **will** get better for it.

Comment: as said, I'm bound to use synchronous ajax. I've been searching for hours for one single solution but didn't find any. Hard day for me :(

Comment: @eddy well, there is no way around. If there was, there would be no drawbacks left to synchronous AJAX and everyone would be using it happily ever after. Frankly, I'm surprised it _doesn't_ freeze firefox.

Comment: Incidentally, you can change the existing ajax calls' behaviour without changing the existing code ;)

Comment: I was wondering if I could pass my post-ajax-respond function as parameter to the function containing the ajax call, so that I can have my manipulations once the script starts responding?

Comment: Did you try using the ajaxStart event and starting the loader it self using jQuery.

Comment: @eddy once you do that, you can use asynchronous ajax as well.

Comment: synchronous ajax = it will freeze.

Comment: Okay. So, it seems like there is no work around. I'll have to recode that rough code again :(

Comment: Try deferred.then() in jQuery. Display loader <b>then</b> initiate the ajax call using this.

Comment: please be a bit more specific on how to use it. I'm not an expert. Also, I'm bound to use synchronous ajax because the data being returned by ajax is being used at a lot of places to change the contents.